# JQuery JS как сделать поиск по маске

Tags: javascript, jquery, поиск

Делаю фильтр хочу реализовать поиск по маске как при поиске файлов
есть шаблон '1x1xxx1'(где х может быть любым символом длина строки ограничена)
и есть строка в которой нужно осуществить поиск

```
'0010000' - подходит - true  
'1010000' - подходит - true  
'0110000' - подходит - true  
'0100010' - не подходит - false
```

Comment: в чем заключается _поиск_? что подается на вход? что должно быть на выходе? А так же было бы не плохо пояснить как, например, строка из примера "0010000" удовлетворяет "маске" - 1x1xxx1

Comment: @Grundy видимо если хоть одна едичинка на своем месте - тру.

Comment: с такой задачей с легкостью справится regexp https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @A50, можете показать пример "легкого справления"? :)

Comment: @Jean-Claude, мне казалось маски немного по другому работают :)

Comment: ```var re = /1[a-zA-Z]+1[a-zA-Z]+1/; 
var str = '1x1xxx1';
var m;
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}```

Comment: @A50, не особо и легко, и особо не понятно как приткнуть в приведенный код строку для проверки, например: `0100010`

Comment: короч разбить строку на массив, где каждая цифра элемент массива и затем проверить `if ( arr[0] == 1 || arr[2] == 1 || arr[6] == 1)  = true`

Comment: @Jean-Claude, это для одной маски :)

Comment: @Grundy в смысле для одной? там же оператор `или` - если хоть одно значение единичка - тру.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, одна маска: '1x1xxx1', для другой придется другое условие писать :)

Comment: ладно, сдуваюсь.

Comment: хотя конечно можно написать функцию на примере моего решения, сначала разобрать маску '1x1xxx1', иксы в топку, единички - искомые индексы массива, далее прогнать if( || )

Comment: @Jean-Claude, тогда уж [array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) вместо if :-)

Comment: сделать что-нибудь вида `str.split('').some(function(letter, i){return mask[i] === '1' ? letter === '1' : false});` где `str` - строка для сравнения. но если планируется потом поддержка - лучше обернуть в функцию с нормальным названием

Comment: @NumminorihSF  спасибо Ваш вариант подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str` - строка, по которой делаем поиск, `mask` - маска для поиска.

```
str.split('').some(function(letter, i){
    return mask[i] === '1' ? letter === '1' : false
});//наружу вернет результат
```

соответственно, по желанию - обернуть в функцию